# BASH: Set the date of the last Monday in a variable

Tags: linux, bash, date

```
today=`date +%a`

if [ "$today" == "Mon" ] 
then
        monday=`date -dmonday +%Y%m%d`
else
        monday=`date -dlast-monday +%Y%m%d`
fi
```

Is it the best way to set the "monday" variable with the date of the last monday?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually your logic is not always setting "last monday". if today is monday, you would get current date value.

I feel your logic is ok. however one thing you may concern about is, `%a` give you a localized weekday name. from man page:

> ```
>  locale’s abbreviated weekday name
> ```

there is another format `%u`, you could use, to make your script more portable.

> %u     day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday